# Why Safari Rendering my Website Incorrectly?

Tags: css, safari

I'm a building responsive website on Django.

When looking at my website on iphone 12 resolution on laptop, everthing lookes good. But when I entered the website on Safari, some parts of design were rendered incorectly.

For example, this is how button looks like on chrome:

[image]

and this is how button look like on the safari:

[image]

This is is a button CSS code:

```
.close-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 334px;
    color: black;
}
```

Button Html CODE:

```
<button class="close-button" onclick="drums()">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Safari//IOS. What OS are you using? And have you tried 50% instead of 50px?

Answer (score -1):

CSS can render differently between browsers. I would look into the specific CSS characteristic and see if you have to alter it or add a different characteristic for it to render properly in Safari.

You can also use the dev tools and inspect it to see what exactly is occurring.

Comment: This doesn’t fully answer the question, it’s more like a (rather general) comment.

Comment: well, I can't comment directly on threads, and wanted to be helpful.